# How to remove background shadow in a slideshow?

Tags: css

I have uploaded a new arrow icon for my slide show but it is displayed within a grey-box. I tried to remove/hide the box with background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); but it remove the image completely.

I would like to display my background-image and only remove the grey-box around it which you can see in the picture – Any Idea on how I can remove the box/shadow around my image?

CSS

```
a.prev-slide:before { 
 background-image: url(http://example/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/example.png);
 background-position: 50% 50%; 
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 content: '';}
```

[Here you can view the grey-box/shadow which I would like to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWiYZ.png)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Consider reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which shadow you're referring to but if you're removing shadows, you should add this to the css of the images' class.

```
box-shadow:none;
```

Like this

```css
a.prev-slide:before { 
box-shadow:none;
background-image: url(http://example/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/example.png); 
background-position: 50% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat; 
content: '';
}
```

IF this is the right class, this is where you add the box-shadow:none;. If not, you might have to give us more of your css to be able to solve it.